# Scala Test, how to take a result from an actor

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest

i have a problem. I'm trying to do some scala tests. My problem is that I don't know how to take the return of a method to test whether it returns a sequence to me or not. How can i do it?
My Test class is: (It works)

```
"The game actor" should {

    "accept a specific numbers of players and notify that the game is started with an initial state" in {
      val gameActor = TestActorRef[GameMatchActor](GameMatchActor.props(NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS))
      val player1 = TestProbe()
      val player2 = TestProbe()

      gameActor ! GamePlayers(Seq(GamePlayer("id1", "player1", player1.ref), GamePlayer("id2", "player2", player2.ref)))
      player1.expectMsgType[MatchFound]
      player1.send(gameActor, PlayerReadyServer("id1", player1.ref))
      player2.expectMsgType[MatchFound]
      player2.send(gameActor, PlayerReadyServer("id2", player2.ref))

      player1.expectMsgType[GamePlayersClient]
      player2.expectMsgType[GamePlayersClient]

    }
  }
```

And the method that return me GamePlayersClient is:

```
private def defineRoles(players: Seq[GamePlayer]): Seq[Player] = {
    var playersRole: Seq[Player] = Seq()
    val rand1 = Random.nextInt(players.length)
    val rand2 = Random.nextInt(players.length)

    for (n <- 0 until players.length) {
      n match {
        case n if n == rand1 || n == rand2 =>
          playersRole = playersRole :+ Impostor(players(n).id, players(n).username, Point2D(0,0))
        case _ => playersRole = playersRole :+ Crewmate(players(n).id, players(n).username, Point2D(0,0))
      }
    }
    playersRole
  }
```

And:

```
// watch the players with the new actor ref
    val playersRole = defineRoles(players)
    this.players.foreach(p => {
      p.actorRef ! GamePlayersClient(playersRole)
      context.watch(p.actorRef)
    })
```

So, how can i take GamePlayersClient(playersRole) and search if inside there's a Sequence of Players and one of they is a "Crewmate". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the `receive`... methods on `TestProbe` to collect the `GamePlayersClient` messages sent to the probe and then use ScalaTest's matchers to assert things about those messages.

For example, you could replace

```
player1.expectMsgType[GamePlayersClient]
```

with

```
val gpcMessageOpt1: Option[GamePlayersClient] = Option(player1.receiveN(1)).flatMap {
  case g: GamePlayersClient => Some(g)
  case _ => None
}

gpcMessageOpt1 shouldNot be(empty) // effectively the same as the expectMessage
```

If the field of interest is `playersRole`, then you might have

```
// To my mind, it's generally OK to do unsafe things like get in a test...
gpcMessageOpt1.get.playersRole shouldNot be(empty)
```